why this code's return value doesn't cover all control path?
TreeNode* searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
        if(root==nullptr)return nullptr;
        if(root->val==val)return root;
        if(root->val<val)return searchBST(root->right,val);
        if(root->val>val)return searchBST(root->left,val);
    }

root is a given BST,val is the target value to search.
when i compile this code there is an error says non-void function does not return a value in all control paths
if i add     return nullptr;in the end of the code it will run.
problem is that how the control flow will go to a path without return value.
assume that root={4,2,7,1,3}
if val=2 or val =7, the code will give the right answer
if val=8,the control flow goes like 4->7->nullptr,and it will return nullptr,which is also right.
so i dont understand how why there is no return value in some control path.
i asked GPT and also do some dedcution in paper,including the target value is and is not in the BST.
i think since i add an     if(root==nullptr)return nullptr;in the front of the code, it's unnecessary to add one in the end.
i really want to know that under what circumstance this recursion will go in to a path with no return value

Lesson learned: sometimes compilers are not very smart. Help yours out a little by adding an else branch. Better yet, use the <=> operator and switch on the resulting value.

make it like if () return else if() return else if() else return last one expression (root->val>val) not needed at all

At a glance, it looks like one of these ifs would always be taken, but for the compiler to be able to assume that, it has to prove to itself that root->val does not change during this method, and that's hard to do.

Since you do not have else. Please provide [mcve] so we could do some experiments.

https://godbolt.org/z/Ph781dj5s

What is root->vals type? If it a custom type, it can have overloaded ==, < and > to compare with an int and they can be all false simulatneously.

the compiler does not necessarily carry out a full analysis of all possible code paths that can occur at runtime. Warnings are based on heuristics and false positives are natural to occur

there are many invalid pointers that are not nullptr. You assume any pointer is either equal to nullptr or can be dereferenced. Generally that is not correct, and whether it is safe to assume in your code we cannot tell without a [mcve].

@Botje unfortunately, you can't switch on std::strong_ordering, as it is a class that doesn't contextually implicitly convert to an integral or enumeration type.

@Caleth TIL. thanks

@Botje TIL too. Such a shame

If val is a floating-point type and either of the values that are being compares is NaN all three comparisons will fail.

Also, std::unreachable seems to make all 3 major compilers understand it correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/86qbabxo7. Though I'd rather just drop the last if (or reorganize the branches to first check <, then > and if neither returned then we know == is true).

This is a false positive of the promoted-to-error warning check. You can help the checker out by rewriting this as an if-else chain, where the last case is unconditional.
TreeNode* searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
    if(root==nullptr) return nullptr;
    else if(root->val==val) return root;
    else if(root->val<val) return searchBST(root->right,val);
    else return searchBST(root->left,val);
}

See it on godbolt

The last else keyword can also (optionally) be removed without changing meaning of the code.    It would be a matter of opinion as to whether that is "better" or not, but either way achieves the goal of helping the checker out.

My favourite setup is to not include the equality check since it will most likely be the rarest to be true and also, it works with floats. if(root) { if(root->val < val) return searchBST(root->right,val); if(val < root->val) return searchBST(root->left,val); } return root;

@TedLyngmo Yes, I would prefer that, but I kept OP's structure to make it easier to follow. For floats, you can't have something that "works" doing that, as anything compares equal to nan if you do

It has being a long time since I used C++, but assuming that it works like in C - the compiler doesn't always know that you include all possible options for the value.
It might be depended on your compiler, but try raising an error if you reach the end of the function without returning.

Wouldn't surprise me if that code is promptly flagged as unreachable :D

Possible - although I believe that all of ">", "==", "<"  operators declare that they return bool, and to check all three cases seems too much for the average compiler. I will admit that using if - else if ... else` would've been preferable, but (A) I would've add assert on the last else for some weird edge cases, and (B) I believe that raise an exception is the minimal fix to the code.

But honestly - I think that the question was already answered in the comments, so the pro and con of my specific solution should possibly be skipped.

Cause you don't have a return value by default. If looks at logic it should always enters in some if. But compilers didn't analyze it, and says that in some cases, if it wouldn't enter in if construction, the code will exit without return value. Instead you should write like this:
TreeNode* searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) 
{
        if(root==nullptr)
           return nullptr;

        if(root->val==val)
           return root;
        else if(root->val<val)
           return searchBST(root->right,val);
        else
           return searchBST(root->left,val); //Any other situations would return this
}


op already knows that they can silence the warning/error by adding an unconditional return. The question is why it is needed.

You'll need else statement to complete if operator. Check if operator syntax
Here is you example:
#include <iostream>
    
typedef struct _tree_node {
      _tree_node* left;
     _tree_node* right;
     int val;
} TreeNode;
    
TreeNode* searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
    TreeNode* ret = nullptr;
    if(nullptr != root){ 
        if(val == root->val) {
            ret = root; 
        } else if( val < root->val ) {
            ret = searchBST(root->left,val);
        } else {
            ret = searchBST(root->right,val);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void print_node(TreeNode* node) {
    std::cout << "node :\n {" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  value = "<<  node->val << ','  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  left = "<<  node->left << ','  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  right = "<<  node->right << ','  << std::endl;
    std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
}
    
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    /**
     Build following tree in stack memory
            1
          /  \ 
         -1   2
         /  \
       -2    0  
    **/       
    TreeNode nodes[5];
    TreeNode* root = &nodes[0];
    root->val = 1;
    TreeNode* left = &nodes[1];
    left->val = -1; 
    root->left = left; 
    TreeNode* tmp = left;
    left = &nodes[2];
    left->val = -2;
    left->left = nullptr;
    left->right = nullptr;
    tmp->left = left;
    TreeNode* right = &nodes[3];
    right->val = 0;
    right->left = nullptr;
    right->right = nullptr;
    tmp->right = right;
    right = &nodes[4];
    right->val = 2;
    right->left = nullptr;
    right->right = nullptr;
    root->right = right;
       
    // Search for node with value 0
    TreeNode *bst = searchBST(root, 0);
    print_node(bst);
    bst = searchBST(root, -2);
    print_node(bst);
    bst = searchBST(root, 2);
    print_node(bst);
    bst = searchBST(root, -1);
    print_node(bst);
    bst = searchBST(root, 1);
    print_node(bst);
    return 0;
}

Check it your self

You don't need typedef struct in C++.

op already knows that they can silence the warning/error by adding an unconditional return. The question is why it is needed.

You and I, being humans with intelligence, can deduce that the if cases cover all possibilities and there's no way to reach the end of the function.  The compiler is not that clever; it knows that it has to return something at the end of the function, but you didn't tell it what.  So it generates an error.  I don't remember what the C++ standard has to say about this, but it's possible that the compiler is required to generate an error in this case.
